# Don't understand shifting, rotating, and LAHF

Tags: assembly, x86, hla

For example, this is the assignment I have

> Write an HLA Assembly program that prompts for an int8 value to inspect and then prints it in binary format. For example, here would be the program output for various entered values
>
> ```
> Gimme a decimal value to print: 15
> 15 is 0000_1111
> Gimme a decimal value to print: 7
> 7 is 0000_0111
> ```

I was able to get the source code of the answer but I'm having trouble understanding.

I put my thought process inside the comments

```
 program binaryoutput;
 #include( "stdlib.hhf" );
 static
   zGivenNumber : int8;  // the value to inspect
 begin binaryoutput;
    //Ask for a decimal number
    stdout.put( "Gimme a decimal value to print: ");
    //Put that number in 'zGivenNumber' (Let's say 7)
    stdin.get( zGivenNumber );
    //Put 'zGivenNumber' inside 'BH' ('BH' now contains 7)
    mov( zGivenNumber, BH);

    stdout.put("Number in binary is: ", nl);

    //Shift left 1 at 'BH' (This makes 'BH' 14)
    shl(1, BH);
    //Not a clue what this is doing
    lahf();
    //Checking to see if 0000_0001 and AH match 0's and 1's
    //(I'm not sure about the % sign as well as where AH came from)
    and( %0000_0001, AH );
    //Print out 'AH' in Eight Bit form
    stdout.puti8(AH);

    shl(1, BH); //2
    lahf();
    and( %0000_0001, AH );
    stdout.puti8(AH);

    shl(1, BH); //Next
    lahf();
    and( %0000_0001, AH );
    stdout.puti8(AH);
    shl(1, BH); //Next
    lahf();
    and( %0000_0001, AH );
    stdout.puti8(AH);
    stdout.put("_");
    shl(1, BH); //Next
    lahf();
    and( %0000_0001, AH );
    stdout.puti8(AH);
    shl(1, BH); //Next
    lahf();
    and( %0000_0001, AH );
    stdout.puti8(AH);
    shl(1, BH); //Next
    lahf();
    and( %0000_0001, AH );
    stdout.puti8(AH);
    shl(1, BH); //Next
    lahf();
    and( %0000_0001, AH );
    stdout.puti8(AH);

 end binaryoutput;
```

We're also not allowed to use loops yet.

I guess I don't understand the shl and the LAHF part

From what I understand, LAHF means Load AH from Flags. So this puts flags into AH. Makes sense that that is where AH is coming from then. Also, shl puts a 0 into bit 0 and then carries over what was in bit 7 into a carry flag. But I'm just not sure what that means.

Comment: What steps have you made to find out what `LAHF` does at all? Once you do find that out, consider: what is the outcome of the `and( %0000_0001, AH )` line?

Comment: From what I understand, LAHF means Load AH from Flags. So this puts flags into AH. Makes sense that that is where AH is coming from then. Also, shl puts a 0 into bit 0 and then carries over what was in bit 7 into a carry flag. But I'm just not sure what that means.

Comment: Please don't waste your time with HLA. I know it's not up to you, but it's horrible that people are forced to learn something like this.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: I've wanted to say that on other questions, but I don't know enough about HLA to know for sure that's it's no longer useful, if it ever was.  I've seen it suggested that HLA was maybe useful when it was invented, but its time has passed as C compilers have advanced, and intrinsics (for SSE or other things) are the way to go for the main problem HLA was trying to solve.  Is any of that accurate?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Wait noo. Don't tell me that :( I thought this was the basis for Assembly Language and it made me interested in it

Comment: HLA is just a wrapper on top of normal assembly language.  It pretty much maps 1:1 to actual asm instructions, except for stuff like `stdout.puti8` which generates a function call to some kind of function.

Comment: @PeterCordes so then what's the point of even learning HLA?

Comment: @CodingIsHardForMe: **There is no point in learning HLA**.  I agree with Daniel's comment.  It may have been useful for some things in the past, but I don't think it's the best choice for anything anymore.  If you want to learn asm, just use it directly.  Use a debugger instead using `stdout.puti8` "debug-print" statements, because CPUs only have a small amount of architectural state (e.g. 16 integer registers, the flags, and the instruction pointer).  Debuggers work extremely well, and can show you everything.

Comment: @CodingIsHardForMe : Peter Cordes is basically right - the time for HLA has passed, if there ever was one. It is neither a higher-level language, nor is it pure assembly. It has all the deficiencies of assembly (is restricted to a particular CPU instruction set), while providing little advantage (if any) over it. If you want to write efficient, portable code, use C. If you need total control over everything, use pure assembly : HLA might generate a dozen instructions that you'll never see in the source, and that was *never* the point of writing assembly, which is my main problem with HLA.

Comment: FWIW, SHL xxx,1 shifts all bits to the left, so the top bit, which would "fall out", is moved into the carry, all other bits move one position to the left and the register is filled up with a zero from the right. So e.g. `C=x 11001101` becomes `C=1 10011010`, where C is the carry..

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Holyshit. I didn't actually realize it was literally shifting

Comment: You're kidding me, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lahf` just loads the cpu flags into the upper byte of the `ax` regishter (`ah`). Bit 0 of the flags (and `ah` after a `lahf` instruction) is the carry flag. So, if the msb of `bh` was 1 then after a left shift the carry would be set. Basically this is just popping off bits from msb to lsb from `bh`.

Comment: Super super stupid question. But what exactly is msb and lsb? I thought `ax` was the upper byte of `ah`, not the other way around. Everything else you said makes sense tho

Comment: @CodingIsHardForMe: MSB = most significant bit (or byte, depending on context).  No wonder you're confused if you thought AX was an 8 bit half of AH, rather than the other way around.  There's a register-subset diagram linked somewhere on the x86 tag wiki page, probably to the x86 wikipedia article.

Comment: msb - most significant bit, lsb - least significant bit. `AX` is the 16-bit register where `ah` (h for high) is the upper 8 bits and `al` (l for low) is the lower 8 bits.

Comment: And so when you specify upper bit of AX, that would be `ah` correct? and `al` for lower bit?

Comment: What you said is correct for `byte` and not `bit`. So, you could use `AH` to get the upper byte/upper 8-bits of `AX` and `AL` for the lower byte/lower 8-bits.

Answer (score 0):

The https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info tag wiki has links to the Intel instruction reference manual, and lots of other good stuff.  If you don't know what LAHF does, why not just look it up?

Also, instead of messing with LAHF, you can just use the carry flag directly.  (x86 shift instructions set CF = the last bit shifted out, which you didn't mention in your HLA comments.)

```
shl  bh, 1
setc al
add  al, '0'   ; AL = '0' or '1', depending on the last bit shifted out of bh
```

Or

```
xor  eax,eax    ; have to zero AL every time, but if you want to get fancy you can then use AL and AH, and then store two digits from AX.
shl  bh, 1
adc  al, '0'    ; AL = '0' + the last bit shifted out of BH
```

The carry flag is special, and has instructions like `adc` / `sbb` / `rcr` / `rcl` to interact with it, as well as the usual `setcc`.

Comment: Oh, I'll look into that, but I'm supposed to use LAHF for my assignment

Comment: @CodingIsHardForMe: ok.  You didn't quote the part of the assignment that said to use LAHF.  Using it usually means you need an extra step compared to just testing a condition with `setcc`, `cmovcc`, or `jcc`, but probably the goal of the assignment is to teach you about the EFLAGS register, and what conditions actually are.  Your last edit to the question indicates confusion about that.